# Copy rows in a specific column if condition is met

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, powerquery

I have a table in 'sheet 1' that has customer name and score (1, 2, 3). I'd like copy specific customer names from sheet 1 based on their score and paste them in 'sheet 2' in either column 1, 2 or 3, based on their scores (each column in sheet 2 represents the score '1', '2' or '3').

For example:

Sheet 1 (original table)
[image]

Sheet 2 (desired split)
[image]

Comment: This is achievable with worksheet formulas (e.g. FILTER), no VBA required.

Comment: If you want to do this with VBA, then share the code (as text) that you have tried so far and identify why it doesn't work (and what does)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been mentioned in comments above by

### [BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853/bigben) Sir,

that it is ***achievable using worksheet functions***, also with the newer **MS365** functions it becomes more **dynamic** **flexible** and **easy** as well. Refer all the **examples** shown, note that you can also achieve this using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd> which is available from **Excel 2010+** onwards. *Posted for your reference*.

---

[image]

---

• Using <kbd>TOROW( )</kbd>, <kbd>UNIQUE( )</kbd> & <kbd>FILTER( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D13</kbd>

```
=TOROW(UNIQUE(B2:B11))
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D14</kbd>

```
=FILTER($A$2:$A$11,D13=$B$2:$B$11)
```

---

The formula in cell in <kbd>D13</kbd> doesn't needs to drag towards right since it will spill automatically, while the formula used in cell <kbd>D14</kbd> needs to fill right, but not required to fill down as it is again going to spill down.(Read here more in **[MS Documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531)** about **Dynamic Spill Array formulas** and their behaviors)

---

• Using <kbd>MAKEARRAY( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D19</kbd>

```
=TOROW(UNIQUE(B2:B11))
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D20</kbd>

```
=MAKEARRAY(MAX(COUNTIFS(B2:B11,B2:B11)),COLUMNS(D19#),LAMBDA(r,c,
           IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(A2:A11,INDEX(D13#,,c)=B2:B11),r),"")))
```

---

Now, this <kbd>MAKEARRAY( )</kbd> function is a <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> helper function, which returns an array with **specified** **rows** -- returns `4` as the **Max** count of values in `Column B`

```
MAX(COUNTIFS(B2:B11,B2:B11))
```

and **columns** -- returns the number of columns it needs to apply or use the `LAMBDA` custom function to work upon.

```
COLUMNS(D19#)
```

based on a custom <kbd>LAMBDA</kbd> calculations -- it iterates each value in the header row <kbd>D13</kbd> to return the output from Column A by column till the `cth` of <kbd>D13#</kbd> and row wise till the `rth` value in the array.

```
INDEX(FILTER(A2:A11,INDEX(D13#,,c)=B2:B11),r)
```

---

Instead of using two formula, we tried to combine it using a <kbd>LET( )</kbd> to make it more **readable** and using defined variables for the formulas which are repeated hence **composing** to make it more **meaningful** to use.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D7</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,A2:A11,
     b,B2:B11,
     c,MAX(COUNTIFS(b,b)),
     ub,TOROW(UNIQUE(b)),
     VSTACK(ub,MAKEARRAY(c,COLUMNS(ub),LAMBDA(r,c,
               IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(a,INDEX(ub,,c)=b),r),"")))))
```

---

Another alternative approach using <kbd>REDUCE( )</kbd> function

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,A2:B11,
     b,TAKE(a,,1),
     c,TAKE(a,,-1),
     d,UNIQUE(c),
     DROP(IFNA(REDUCE("",d,LAMBDA(x,y,HSTACK(x,VSTACK(TOROW(y),
          FILTER(b,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(c,y))))))),""),,1))
```

---

Like I said above, you can also perform this task using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>, so here are the steps you need to follow, this is more simple and easy using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd> UI.

[image]

---

- Firstly, convert your range of data into a table, by selecting some of the cells in the data and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, immediately you will be popped up a small window like as below, click on the check box that reads as *My table has headers* (**Note**: Excel is smart to detect that, however if it fails, make sure to select the checkbox).

[image]

---

- You can rename the Table from <kbd>Design</kbd> Tab, now on selection in some of the cells in Table, press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>PT</kbd> or from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> From <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> Group --> Click on <kbd>From Table/Range</kbd> --> This opens the PQ Editor Window with your table data.

---

- Now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press **Done**

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="CustScoretbl"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Score"}, {{"All", each _, type table [Customer=text, Score=number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.AddIndexColumn([All],"Index",1,1)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Custom"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Custom", {"Customer", "Score", "Index"}, {"Customer", "Score", "Index"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom", {{"Score", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom", {{"Score", type text}}, "en-US")[Score]), "Score", "Customer"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to `Excel` --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a new sheet with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Hope this helps! Download the workbook from here: **[link](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2cjXjXtS0mQyOtUj4Z?e=fMMQwV)**

Comment: Thanks very much Mayukh, I will try these options. For the power query option, is it possible that that if the score changes, I refresh the output sheet that would have been already created via the 'close and load to' or will I have to redo the steps mentioned above?

Comment: Thanks very much Mayukh, I used the power query and it worked

Comment: Glad to know you got it resolved.